# CSS margin spacing differently for top and sides

Tags: css, margin, spacing

I hope someone can help me, as I feel rather dumb for asking such a question here. I am not a web designer, but have been stuck with a task of creating a basic layout. The layout will be used on an integrated device with a standard browser, so some of the browser specific CSS tags .. i.e: -moz-border-radius will not necesarily need to work with IE and such.

I have a 1024x768 page that I want to have a few block sections on. These sections will have 4px of space on every side. So a 2x2 grid should have 4px gap(black) on the outside of the whole site, while the insides have 8px gap between the boxes (4px on the right side of one box, and 4px on the left, or 4px on the bottom of one, and 4px on the top, et)

When I set each of these div's CSS to margin: 4px; I get the outside gap of 4px. I also get a horizontal gap of 8px between the left and right sides of the boxes. The problem is that the vertical spacing is 4px, like one of the quarter boxes is not applying a top or bottom margin. I don't think this is something that is supposed to happen, so I figure I made a mistake somewhere.

Thanks in advance -- this place is awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's due to 'margin collapsing': the smallest adjacent vertical margin is ignored in the most simple case.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply as well. Please see question 2 aboe if you have any insight. thanks again!

Comment: One option is to apply a transparent single pixel border around each object. Of course, you'll then have to account for that change, but it's a simple quick fix if you're using absolute values for dimensions.

Comment: Btw, this is a good reference: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins

Answer (score 2):

Try using padding instead of margin.

The largest margin between two objects is used as the space between them.

If `object_a` has a margin of 4, and `object_b` has a margin of 6, if you place them side by side, they will have a margin of 6.

If you use padding, it creates more of a bubble around them, and combines the distance.

If `object_a` has a padding of 4, and `object_b` has a padding of 6, if you place them side by side, they will have a padding of 10.

---

UPDATE -- thanks to @Bobby Jack

Horizontal margins never collapse. Only vertical.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I learn something new everyday. Do you happen to know of the simplest way to achieve this with my layout? When I use margin, it creates space outside of the div. When I use padding, it creates space inside the div, in turn making the div 4px wider on each side. I can see using this idea with nesting the div's and keeping the outside div transparent with a padding of 4px. I just dont know if this is the most elegant way, if so no problem. Just want to make sure im not missing something

Comment: It's important to note that margin collapsing only affects vertical margins. Your use of the term 'side by side' might be taken to mean otherwise.

Comment: @ Bobby -- Really? I've never heard of that, do you have an article? It seems that it has always affected me.

Comment: @ David -- you can adjust the margins specifically so that if you need more or less, its 8px on certain sides and not on others, etc.

Comment: from the spec (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#x26): "In CSS 2.1, horizontal margins never collapse" ;-)